# What is the ulimit -N 15 option?

Tags: linux, ulimit

In the project I am currently developping, I need to use the program `ulimit`. When I use `ulimit -a` I got the list of the different options available with a small description except `-N 15` which the value on my system is `unlimited`. So my question is what does this option do? I already looked at the `man` but I did not find any explanations.

Here is the list of options and their values on my system :

```
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         unlimited
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       257371
-n: file descriptors                1024
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  16384
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 257371
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -N option allows to access each field of ulimit using an integer identifier. For example `ulimit -N 0` correspond to `ulimit -t` (cpu time) and `ulimit -N 14` correspond to `ulimit -r` (max rt priority).

This is specially useful when using the command `ulimit` in a script file, allowing an easy access to each/any field.